# Set up TeXLipse for correct BibTeX creation / autocompletion

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texlipse, build-system

When I try to create my file with TeXLipse, it never creates the bibliography information correctly. I set up everything as described in the various tutorials.

The current setup is like this:

```
/
/src
/src/doc.tex
/src/Bibliography.bib
```

I use `\bibliography{Bibliography}` to include the file and `\cite{abc}` to cite. But TeXLipse doesn't seem to build the bibliography correctly, and also it doesn't recognize the references for autocompletion when using `\cite{`...

Do I somehow need to set up the builders in a different order, and if so, how do I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe you're missing \bibliographystyle{plain}?

Answer (score 2):

The following is too long for a comment.

It's important to provide a minimal example. Word phrases like "TeXLipse doesn't seem to build the bibliography correctly" aren't useful. We need specific information. However I can imagine that you are using TeX Live. In TeX Live you have restrited rules for including such file. The rules are located in the file `texmf.cnf`. It is located in the folder: `texlive/2011/texmf/web2c`. The file contains next to the definitions a documentation where you can find:

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

So I suggest to change the parameter `openout_any=p` to `openout_any=a`  whereby the changes took place in the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, it seems that TeXLipse does not like sub-folders

More details on this other conversation can be of help 
[Bibtex not showing using TexLipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48005/bibtex-not-showing-using-texlipse)
(too bad it has been closed)

I am using MikTeX and, if I avoid using subfolders, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.
The problem still seems to be that Bibtex is not run!