# Bibtex not showing using TexLipse

Tags: bibtex, texlipse

I have created a project within TexLipse and right before the end of the document I use the command `\bibliography{bibtexfile} \bibliographystyle{plain}` to create the bibtex reference section. However, when I build my project in TexLipse, the reference section does not show. Also selecting "Run BibTex on next build" does not have any effect.

If I move `\bibliography{bibtexfile} \bibliographystyle{plain}` to the line after `\maketitle`, the section **is** created. But I want the section at the end of my document, not the beginning.

If I use a different editor, like TexMaker, and do: `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`, everything works fine. It seems like TexLipse does not run `bibtex` at all.

Even with a .bat file everything works fine:

```
pdflatex main.tex  
bibtex main.aux  
pdflatex main.tex  
pdflatex main.tex
```

What could be the problem?

---

**OK! Seems like I fixed it myself**
I use \input{} to include external files, but apparently TexLipse does not like it when the commands `\bibliography{bibtexfile} \bibliographystyle{plain}` are externally called. TexLipse wants them in the main tex file.

Comment: did you also define a `\bibliographystyle{}`? Did you use `\cite{key}` in the document or `\nocite{*}` to output all references? What happens if you run bibtex from the command line?

Comment: Yes I use the `\bibliographystyle{}` command and also `\cite{key}`. It all works fine when I do it with texmaker, with command line or even with a bat file: 
`pdflatex main.tex
bibtex main.aux
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex` (6 references are created). Even weirder: when I put the `\bibliography{bibtexfile}
\bibliographystyle{plain}` after `\maketitle`, TexLipse creates the references without a problem.

Comment: Disagree with the closing... this is a very useful question.

Comment: Diasgree with closing. This is applicable to anybody using TeXlipse. (and I have the same problem right now ;))

Comment: Running "Project -> Clean..." sometimes helps if TeXlipse/BibTeX are not working properly.